# MQTT not connecting immediately?

Tags: ios, swift, mqtt, cocoamqtt

I'm using CocoaMqtt, which is not connecting immediately taking 6-7sec time. Why which is taking too much time, and how to resolve it?

My code is:

```
func connectMqtt(mqttProfile: MQTTConfiguration, handler: @escaping (Result<String,MQTTError>)->()){
    let clientID =  String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
    mqttReference = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: mqttProfile.baseURL, port: UInt16(mqttProfile.port))
    mqttReference?.username = mqttProfile.userName
    mqttReference?.password = mqttProfile.password        
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [self] in
        //mqttReference?.logLevel = .debug
        mqttReference?.enableSSL = true
        mqttReference?.sslSettings = [
            GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true),
            GCDAsyncSocketUseCFStreamForTLS: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false),
            kCFStreamSSLPeerName as String: "" as NSString,
            GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMin: NSNumber(integerLiteral: Int(SSLProtocol.tlsProtocol1.rawValue)),
            GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMax: NSNumber(integerLiteral: Int(SSLProtocol.tlsProtocol12.rawValue)),
        ]
        
        ///mqttReference?.keepAlive = 300
        ///mqttReference?.cleanSession = false
        mqttReference?.autoReconnect = true
        mqttReference?.backgroundOnSocket = mqttProfile.allowBackgroundMQTT
        mqttReference?.delegate = self
        do {
            if((mqttReference?.connect())!){
                mqttReference?.didConnectAck = { mqtt, ack in
                    switch ack {
                    case .accept:
                        handler(.success("Connected"))
                        self.isMqttConncted = true
                        privateVariables.shared.mqttEnabled = true
                        TestClient.shared.mqttConnected = true
                        self.didReciveMqttMessage(.init(topic: "connectivity", string: "connected"), 1)
                    default:
                        handler(.failure(.badURL))
                        self.isMqttConncted = false
                        privateVariables.shared.mqttEnabled = false
                        self.didReciveMqttMessage(.init(topic: "connectivity", string: "disconnected"), 0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Delegate:

```
internal func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
    switch ack {
    case .accept:
        SDKdebug().debug(value:"mqtt connected")
        self.isMqttConncted = true
        privateVariables.shared.mqttEnabled = true
        TestClient.shared.mqttConnected = true
        self.didReciveMqttMessage(.init(topic: "connectivity", string: "connected"), 1)
    default:
        
        SDKdebug().debug(value:ack.description)
        
        self.isMqttConncted = false
        privateVariables.shared.mqttEnabled = false
        TestClient.shared.mqttConnected = false
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.startToMQTT { (sttaus) in
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be a lot of potential issues: network, DNS lookup, slow broker response...

A few things to try:

1. monitor network traffic using a tool like Wireshark
2. Retry the connection attempt [using a CLI](https://hivemq.github.io/mqtt-cli/) and see if you can reproduce the delay
3. monitor the execution time of each connect step in the code
4. Try connecting to a different broker - potentially a [public broker](http://www.mqtt-dashboard.com) to see if the problem persists
5. It could be a problem in the CocoaMQTT client - worth searching existing and closed issues

The objective being to reduce the problem area to identify the root cause.

With these steps you should be able to whittle down to where the problem is.